# How do I make a Java friendly API for case classes with optional fields

Tags: scala, api-design, scala-java-interop

I'm creating some case classes in Scala that I use to persist data mongodb. The client app is written in Java and using my repository by passing in instances of these case classes.

It works fine, unless I use optional fields:

```
case class Person (name: String, email: Option[String])
```

Now from Java I don't want to reference Scala's Option, so I'd prefer to override a constructor that allows the client to call something like

```
new Person("Jack", "jack@ripper.com");
```

A factory method on the companion object would also be OK. I'm looking for a solution that allows me to write Java without any scala deps, preferably no more convoluted than calling a constructor. Thoughts?

Comment: How would java callers indicate a missing email? Another constructor or (shudder) null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why is this insufficient?

```
case class Person (name: String, email: Option[String]) {
    def this(name: String, email: String) {
        this(name, Option(email))
    }
}
```

Surely, it still uses `Option[String]`, but it remains invisible to the client. The only problem is that the Java client code will still see both constructors.

Comment: Even better, you could make the default constructor a private[packagename] one and then the client would only see the other constructor (assuming you have no Scala clients).

Comment: I was lucky enough to get rid of the requirement for Java, so I can't remember why the simple constructor wasn't good enough. I started there and abandoned that path for some reason. I'd start there again if it ever comes up.

Comment: Ah, I just recovered the problem: salat (the framework I'm using for MongoDB integration) doesn't like multiple constructors and will fail to do its conversions if you have them.